# Escaping MySQL reserved words with Python dbapi

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python, python-db-api

I am looking for a nice "pythonic" and "SQL-Injection-free" solution for a problem with reserved words in MySQL.

I have the following code:

```
alter_sql = 'ALTER TABLE %s ADD COLUMN %s TEXT'      
cursor.execute(alter_sql, sql_params)
```

The problem occurs when column name is something like 'index', 'int', 'limit' ....

In MySQL shell I can do:

```
ALTER TABLE test ADD COLUMN test.limit;
```

or

```
ALTER TABLE test ADD COLUMN `limit`;
```

but not

```
ALTER TABLE test ADD COLUMN 'test.limit';
```

How can I achieve that with Python and MySQLdb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this will work:

```
alter_sql = 'ALTER TABLE `%s` ADD COLUMN `%s` TEXT'
```

**UPDATE**: This seems not to work, because binding parameters this way will add single quotes, as MySQLdb supposes this is a string literal.

Alternatively, you can append the table name before the column name?

```
table_name = MySQLdb.escape_string(table_name)
escaped_column_name = MySQLdb.escape_string(column_name)
column_name = '`%s`.`%s`' % (table_name, escaped_column_name)

alter_sql = 'ALTER TABLE %s ADD COLUMN %s TEXT' % (table_name, column_name)
```

This way, you must escape them manually, to avoid binding them and adding single quotes around it.

Comment: How is the query you are using working then? it will output something like: `ALTER TABLE 'mytable' ADD COLUMN ...` which does not work...

Comment: The resulting SQL would be ``ALTER TABLE '`test`' ADD COLUMN '`limit`' TEXT`` which is invalid.

Comment: Your original query. Didn't it output something similar to what I put in my comment? I tried that and it did not work: "Check the syntax whatever ..." error

Answer (score 0):

From [here](http://www.kitebird.com/articles/pydbapi.html):

> You can issue the same statement by using %s placeholder markers and binding the appropriate values to them:
>
> ```
> cursor.execute("""UPDATE animal SET name = %s
>                   WHERE name = %s
>                """, ("snake", "turtle"))
> print "Number of rows updated: %d" % cursor.rowcount
> ```
>
> Note the following points about the form of the preceding execute() call:
>
> - The %s placeholder marker should occur once for each value that is to be inserted into the statement string.
> - No quotes should be placed around the %s markers; MySQLdb supplies quotes for you as necessary.
> - Following the statement string argument to execute(), provide a tuple containing the values to be bound to the placeholders, in the order they should appear within the string. If you have only a single value x, specify it as (x,) to indicate a single-element tuple.
> - Bind the Python None value to a placeholder to insert an SQL NULL value into the statement.

So, based on that, you should just pre-process your arguments to see if they're in a list of reserved keywords, and if so, prefix the table name to the column name, for eg.

```
RESERVED_KEYWORDS = ['LIMIT', 'INT', 'INDEX']
table_name = 'TESTING'
column_name = 'LIMIT'
if column_name in RESERVED_KEYWORDS:
    column_name = '%s.%s' % (table_name, column_name)
sql_params = [table_name, column_name]
alter_sql = 'ALTER TABLE %s ADD COLUMN %s TEXT'      
cursor.execute(alter_sql, sql_params)
```

Comment: I tried that, but MySQLdb created the following SQL: ALTER TABLE testing ADD COLUMN 'test.limit'; Which is invalid due to the quotes around test.limit.

Comment: If you are 100% sure your input is sanitized you could just do `sql_query = alter_sql % sql_params; cursor.execute(sql_query)` to interpolate the SQL statement and parameters first, and then execute it. Not exactly the best method, but should work.