# python mysql - find in loop for every column name string has any reserved keywords used

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to implement an auto loader from csv to database in python. Here I used `for loop` to read the column names in csv. Sometimes it might happen that the column names could be same as reserved keywords of MySQL. So I want to find out a way if I can filter such strings that are same as reserved keywords. I saw many posts who suggested to do it manually adding all the keywords in a new table and then compare. But there is high chance of loosing a keyword while doing so and also extremely laborious process.

Or would it be a feasable way to catch the error and process the letters from error? Would it be possible to identify like that?

So is there a way how to find out if my query in loop has an input string which is same as reserved keyword of MySQL using python. Or any alternative how to find?

I am aware how to handle a keyword Eg: with back tick or in square brackets. But that is second step. First I have to know if there is a string that could be a keyword. How do I do this without creating a table/list of keywords. I am sure some words might be missed or there could be a typo by adding manually.

I have did some research and found an interesting almost similar but not same question in the following link. This answer did not support my use.
[Escaping MySQL reserved words with Python dbapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10617656/escaping-mysql-reserved-words-with-python-dbapi)

Looking forward for your support and encouragement. I am a total newbee in SQL. Thank you

Comment: Why isn't escaping the column names an option for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this what you require but check it out;

Option 1: Here is a complete list of all the keywords in MySQL. You can compare your column names with them and modify them accordingly

```
['SELECT', 'DELETE', 'BIGINT', 'BEGIN', 'END', 'INTERVAL', 'COUNT', '_FILENAME', 'GROUP', 'ACCESSIBLE', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACTION', 'ADD', 'AFTER', 'AGAINST', 'AGGREGATE', 'ALGORITHM', 'ALL', 'ALTER', 'ALWAYS', 'ANALYSE', 'ANALYZE', 'AND', 'ANY', 'AS', 'ASC', 'ASCII', 'ASENSITIVE', 'AT', 'AUTOEXTEND_SIZE', 'AUTO_INCREMENT', 'AVG', 'AVG_ROW_LENGTH', 'BACKUP', 'BEFORE', 'BEGIN', 'BETWEEN', 'BIGINT', 'BINARY', 'BINLOG', 'BIT', 'BLOB', 'BLOCK', 'BOOL', 'BOOLEAN', 'BOTH', 'BTREE', 'BY', 'BYTE', 'CACHE', 'CALL', 'CASCADE', 'CASCADED', 'CASE', 'CATALOG_NAME', 'CHAIN', 'CHANGE', 'CHANGED', 'CHANNEL', 'CHAR', 'CHARACTER', 'CHARSET', 'CHECK', 'CHECKSUM', 'CIPHER', 'CLASS_ORIGIN', 'CLIENT', 'CLOSE', 'COALESCE', 'CODE', 'COLLATE', 'COLLATION', 'COLUMN', 'COLUMNS', 'COLUMN_FORMAT', 'COLUMN_NAME', 'COMMENT', 'COMMIT', 'COMMITTED', 'COMPACT', 'COMPLETION', 'COMPRESSED', 'COMPRESSION', 'CONCURRENT', 'CONDITION', 'CONNECTION', 'CONSISTENT', 'CONSTRAINT', 'CONSTRAINT_CATALOG', 'CONSTRAINT_NAME', 'CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA', 'CONTAINS', 'CONTEXT', 'CONTINUE', 'CONVERT', 'CPU', 'CREATE', 'CROSS', 'CUBE', 'CURRENT', 'CURRENT_DATE', 'CURRENT_TIME', 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP', 'CURRENT_USER', 'CURSOR', 'CURSOR_NAME', 'DATA', 'DATABASE', 'DATABASES', 'DATAFILE', 'DATE', 'DATETIME', 'DAY', 'DAY_HOUR', 'DAY_MICROSECOND', 'DAY_MINUTE', 'DAY_SECOND', 'DEALLOCATE', 'DEC', 'DECIMAL', 'DECLARE', 'DEFAULT', 'DEFAULT_AUTH', 'DEFINER', 'DELAYED', 'DELAY_KEY_WRITE', 'DELETE', 'DESC', 'DESCRIBE', 'DES_KEY_FILE', 'DETERMINISTIC', 'DIAGNOSTICS', 'DIRECTORY', 'DISABLE', 'DISCARD', 'DISK', 'DISTINCT', 'DISTINCTROW', 'DIV', 'DO', 'DOUBLE', 'DROP', 'DUAL', 'DUMPFILE', 'DUPLICATE', 'DYNAMIC', 'EACH', 'ELSE', 'ELSEIF', 'ENABLE', 'ENCLOSED', 'ENCRYPTION', 'END', 'ENDS', 'ENGINE', 'ENGINES', 'ENUM', 'ERROR', 'ERRORS', 'ESCAPE', 'ESCAPED', 'EVENT', 'EVENTS', 'EVERY', 'EXCHANGE', 'EXECUTE', 'EXISTS', 'EXIT', 'EXPANSION', 'EXPIRE', 'EXPLAIN', 'EXPORT', 'EXTENDED', 'EXTENT_SIZE', 'FALSE', 'FAST', 'FAULTS', 'FETCH', 'FIELDS', 'FILE', 'FILE_BLOCK_SIZE', 'FILTER', 'FIRST', 'FIXED', 'FLOAT', 'FLOAT4', 'FLOAT8', 'FLUSH', 'FOLLOWS', 'FOR', 'FORCE', 'FOREIGN', 'FORMAT', 'FOUND', 'FROM', 'FULL', 'FULLTEXT', 'FUNCTION', 'GENERAL', 'GENERATED', 'GEOMETRY', 'GEOMETRYCOLLECTION', 'GET', 'GET_FORMAT', 'GLOBAL', 'GRANT', 'GRANTS', 'GROUP', 'GROUP_REPLICATION', 'HANDLER', 'HASH', 'HAVING', 'HELP', 'HIGH_PRIORITY', 'HOST', 'HOSTS', 'HOUR', 'HOUR_MICROSECOND', 'HOUR_MINUTE', 'HOUR_SECOND', 'IDENTIFIED', 'IF', 'IGNORE', 'IGNORE_SERVER_IDS', 'IMPORT', 'IN', 'INDEX', 'INDEXES', 'INFILE', 'INITIAL_SIZE', 'INNER', 'INOUT', 'INSENSITIVE', 'INSERT', 'INSERT_METHOD', 'INSTALL', 'INSTANCE', 'INT', 'INT1', 'INT2', 'INT3', 'INT4', 'INT8', 'INTEGER', 'INTERVAL', 'INTO', 'INVOKER', 'IO', 'IO_AFTER_GTIDS', 'IO_BEFORE_GTIDS', 'IO_THREAD', 'IPC', 'IS', 'ISOLATION', 'ISSUER', 'ITERATE', 'JOIN', 'JSON', 'KEY', 'KEYS', 'KEY_BLOCK_SIZE', 'KILL', 'LANGUAGE', 'LAST', 'LEADING', 'LEAVE', 'LEAVES', 'LEFT', 'LESS', 'LEVEL', 'LIKE', 'LIMIT', 'LINEAR', 'LINES', 'LINESTRING', 'LIST', 'LOAD', 'LOCAL', 'LOCALTIME', 'LOCALTIMESTAMP', 'LOCK', 'LOCKS', 'LOGFILE', 'LOGS', 'LONG', 'LONGBLOB', 'LONGTEXT', 'LOOP', 'LOW_PRIORITY', 'MASTER', 'MASTER_AUTO_POSITION', 'MASTER_BIND', 'MASTER_CONNECT_RETRY', 'MASTER_DELAY', 'MASTER_HEARTBEAT_PERIOD', 'MASTER_HOST', 'MASTER_LOG_FILE', 'MASTER_LOG_POS', 'MASTER_PASSWORD', 'MASTER_PORT', 'MASTER_RETRY_COUNT', 'MASTER_SERVER_ID', 'MASTER_SSL', 'MASTER_SSL_CA', 'MASTER_SSL_CAPATH', 'MASTER_SSL_CERT', 'MASTER_SSL_CIPHER', 'MASTER_SSL_CRL', 'MASTER_SSL_CRLPATH', 'MASTER_SSL_KEY', 'MASTER_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT', 'MASTER_TLS_VERSION', 'MASTER_USER', 'MATCH', 'MAXVALUE', 'MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR', 'MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR', 'MAX_ROWS', 'MAX_SIZE', 'MAX_STATEMENT_TIME', 'MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR', 'MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS', 'MEDIUM', 'MEDIUMBLOB', 'MEDIUMINT', 'MEDIUMTEXT', 'MEMORY', 'MERGE', 'MESSAGE_TEXT', 'MICROSECOND', 'MIDDLEINT', 'MIGRATE', 'MINUTE', 'MINUTE_MICROSECOND', 'MINUTE_SECOND', 'MIN_ROWS', 'MOD', 'MODE', 'MODIFIES', 'MODIFY', 'MONTH', 'MULTILINESTRING', 'MULTIPOINT', 'MULTIPOLYGON', 'MUTEX', 'MYSQL_ERRNO', 'NAME', 'NAMES', 'NATIONAL', 'NATURAL', 'NCHAR', 'NDB', 'NDBCLUSTER', 'NEVER', 'NEW', 'NEXT', 'NO', 'NODEGROUP', 'NONBLOCKING', 'NONE', 'NOT', 'NO_WAIT', 'NO_WRITE_TO_BINLOG', 'NULL', 'NUMBER', 'NUMERIC', 'NVARCHAR', 'OFFSET', 'OLD_PASSWORD', 'ON', 'ONE', 'ONLY', 'OPEN', 'OPTIMIZE', 'OPTIMIZER_COSTS', 'OPTION', 'OPTIONALLY', 'OPTIONS', 'OR', 'ORDER', 'OUT', 'OUTER', 'OUTFILE', 'OWNER', 'PACK_KEYS', 'PAGE', 'PARSER', 'PARSE_GCOL_EXPR', 'PARTIAL', 'PARTITION', 'PARTITIONING', 'PARTITIONS', 'PASSWORD', 'PHASE', 'PLUGIN', 'PLUGINS', 'PLUGIN_DIR', 'POINT', 'POLYGON', 'PORT', 'PRECEDES', 'PRECISION', 'PREPARE', 'PRESERVE', 'PREV', 'PRIMARY', 'PRIVILEGES', 'PROCEDURE', 'PROCESSLIST', 'PROFILE', 'PROFILES', 'PROXY', 'PURGE', 'QUARTER', 'QUERY', 'QUICK', 'RANGE', 'READ', 'READS', 'READ_ONLY', 'READ_WRITE', 'REAL', 'REBUILD', 'RECOVER', 'REDOFILE', 'REDO_BUFFER_SIZE', 'REDUNDANT', 'REFERENCES', 'REGEXP', 'RELAY', 'RELAYLOG', 'RELAY_LOG_FILE', 'RELAY_LOG_POS', 'RELAY_THREAD', 'RELEASE', 'RELOAD', 'REMOVE', 'RENAME', 'REORGANIZE', 'REPAIR', 'REPEAT', 'REPEATABLE', 'REPLACE', 'REPLICATE_DO_DB', 'REPLICATE_DO_TABLE', 'REPLICATE_IGNORE_DB', 'REPLICATE_IGNORE_TABLE', 'REPLICATE_REWRITE_DB', 'REPLICATE_WILD_DO_TABLE', 'REPLICATE_WILD_IGNORE_TABLE', 'REPLICATION', 'REQUIRE', 'RESET', 'RESIGNAL', 'RESTORE', 'RESTRICT', 'RESUME', 'RETURN', 'RETURNED_SQLSTATE', 'RETURNS', 'REVERSE', 'REVOKE', 'RIGHT', 'RLIKE', 'ROLLBACK', 'ROLLUP', 'ROTATE', 'ROUTINE', 'ROW', 'ROWS', 'ROW_COUNT', 'ROW_FORMAT', 'RTREE', 'SAVEPOINT', 'SCHEDULE', 'SCHEMA', 'SCHEMAS', 'SCHEMA_NAME', 'SECOND', 'SECOND_MICROSECOND', 'SECURITY', 'SELECT', 'SENSITIVE', 'SEPARATOR', 'SERIAL', 'SERIALIZABLE', 'SERVER', 'SESSION', 'SET', 'SHARE', 'SHOW', 'SHUTDOWN', 'SIGNAL', 'SIGNED', 'SIMPLE', 'SLAVE', 'SLOW', 'SMALLINT', 'SNAPSHOT', 'SOCKET', 'SOME', 'SONAME', 'SOUNDS', 'SOURCE', 'SPATIAL', 'SPECIFIC', 'SQL', 'SQLEXCEPTION', 'SQLSTATE', 'SQLWARNING', 'SQL_AFTER_GTIDS', 'SQL_AFTER_MTS_GAPS', 'SQL_BEFORE_GTIDS', 'SQL_BIG_RESULT', 'SQL_BUFFER_RESULT', 'SQL_CACHE', 'SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS', 'SQL_NO_CACHE', 'SQL_SMALL_RESULT', 'SQL_THREAD', 'SQL_TSI_DAY', 'SQL_TSI_HOUR', 'SQL_TSI_MINUTE', 'SQL_TSI_MONTH', 'SQL_TSI_QUARTER', 'SQL_TSI_SECOND', 'SQL_TSI_WEEK', 'SQL_TSI_YEAR', 'SSL', 'STACKED', 'START', 'STARTING', 'STARTS', 'STATS_AUTO_RECALC', 'STATS_PERSISTENT', 'STATS_SAMPLE_PAGES', 'STATUS', 'STOP', 'STORAGE', 'STORED', 'STRAIGHT_JOIN', 'STRING', 'SUBCLASS_ORIGIN', 'SUBJECT', 'SUBPARTITION', 'SUBPARTITIONS', 'SUPER', 'SUSPEND', 'SWAPS', 'SWITCHES', 'TABLE', 'TABLES', 'TABLESPACE', 'TABLE_CHECKSUM', 'TABLE_NAME', 'TEMPORARY', 'TEMPTABLE', 'TERMINATED', 'TEXT', 'THAN', 'THEN', 'TIME', 'TIMESTAMP', 'TIMESTAMPADD', 'TIMESTAMPDIFF', 'TINYBLOB', 'TINYINT', 'TINYTEXT', 'TO', 'TRAILING', 'TRANSACTION', 'TRIGGER', 'TRIGGERS', 'TRUE', 'TRUNCATE', 'TYPE', 'TYPES', 'UNCOMMITTED', 'UNDEFINED', 'UNDO', 'UNDOFILE', 'UNDO_BUFFER_SIZE', 'UNICODE', 'UNINSTALL', 'UNION', 'UNIQUE', 'UNKNOWN', 'UNLOCK', 'UNSIGNED', 'UNTIL', 'UPDATE', 'UPGRADE', 'USAGE', 'USE', 'USER', 'USER_RESOURCES', 'USE_FRM', 'USING', 'UTC_DATE', 'UTC_TIME', 'UTC_TIMESTAMP', 'VALIDATION', 'VALUE', 'VALUES', 'VARBINARY', 'VARCHAR', 'VARCHARACTER', 'VARIABLES', 'VARYING', 'VIEW', 'VIRTUAL', 'WAIT', 'WARNINGS', 'WEEK', 'WEIGHT_STRING', 'WHEN', 'WHERE', 'WHILE', 'WITH', 'WITHOUT', 'WORK', 'WRAPPER', 'WRITE', 'X509', 'XA', 'XID', 'XML', 'XOR', 'YEAR', 'YEAR_MONTH', 'ZEROFILL', 'ACCOUNT', 'ALWAYS', 'CHANNEL', 'COMPRESSION', 'ENCRYPTION', 'FILE_BLOCK_SIZE', 'FILTER', 'FOLLOWS', 'GENERATED', 'GROUP_REPLICATION', 'INSTANCE', 'JSON', 'MASTER_TLS_VERSION', 'NEVER', 'OPTIMIZER_COSTS', 'PARSE_GCOL_EXPR', 'PRECEDES', 'REPLICATE_DO_DB', 'REPLICATE_DO_TABLE', 'REPLICATE_IGNORE_DB', 'REPLICATE_IGNORE_TABLE', 'REPLICATE_REWRITE_DB', 'REPLICATE_WILD_DO_TABLE', 'REPLICATE_WILD_IGNORE_TABLE', 'ROTATE', 'STACKED', 'STORED', 'VALIDATION', 'VIRTUAL', 'WITHOUT', 'XID', 'OLD_PASSWORD']
```

**Scraped** from [MySQL Keywords](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html)

Option 2: There are few ways to ignore the keywords in the query; Check these links

[Using keywords in tables or columns](https://www.ionos.com/help/hosting/using-mysql-databases-for-web-projects/mysql-57-reserved-words/)

[SO Answer on using reserved words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446377/syntax-error-due-to-using-a-reserved-word-as-a-table-or-column-name-in-mysql)

TLDR:

```
create table Test(`id` integer, `default` varchar(100));
insert into Test(`id`, `default`) values(1, "Hello");
select * from Test;
```

Option 3: (not sure but) I think you can also use "[]" to ignore the keywords;

For eg: "select [**default**] from table;"

where **default** is a keyword

Comment: But writing manually as a list or table is what I want to avoid. I appreciate your answer though. Thank you

Comment: @Priya then you can stick with option 2 and add backtick to every column name - that works both for keywords and non-keywords. Am I getting you right there?

Comment: @AvergaGod Ah okay! I was with the idea that it doesn't work for non keywords. I mean it considers backtick also as a character and create columnname with back tick. Eg: ``ID` as column name instead of just `ID` without backticks. Thanks a lot